# Streaming Video over UDP with ffmpeg - h264 low latency

Tags: ffmpeg, ethernet, video-streaming, udp

Hello fellow video codec enthousiasts,

I'm curenntly working on a little system to play games in my living room using my office's computer. I'm trying to stream my screen through UDP with the lowest latency possible using ffmpeg. Right now my commands look like this :

**SERVER SIDE**

```
ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -f x11grab  -i :0.0+0,0  -preset ultrafast -tune zero_latency -f mpegts udp://{CLIENT_IP}:8000
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -probesize 20000 -analyzeduration 1 -strict experimental -framedrop -f mpegts udp://{SERVER_IP}:8000
```

While my video quality on the recieving side is on point (actually I'd like to use a different muxer since mpegts is kinda ugly), I get a full second of delay right now.

The weird thing is, if I reduce the bitrate on the server side, the delay stays the same.

Would you know of a way to reduce it?

Comment: Did you check/try everything here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658873/how-to-minimize-the-delay-in-a-live-streaming-with-ffmpeg Regardless, I think OBS is a more suitable tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

For streaming `mpegts` with minimum latency, there is one more "secret argument":

```
`-omit_video_pes_length 0`
```

The default is `-omit_video_pes_length 1`, and omitting the length adds a latency of one more frame.

---

**SERVER SIDE:**
`ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -preset ultrafast -tune zero_latency -f mpegts -omit_video_pes_length 1 udp://{CLIENT_IP}:8000`

---

For getting minimal latency with FFplay, use `-flags low_delay`, `-probesize 32` and `-vf setpts=0` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658873/how-to-minimize-the-delay-in-a-live-streaming-with-ffmpeg).

**CLIENT SIDE:**
`ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 1 -strict experimental -framedrop -f mpegts -vf setpts=0 udp://{SERVER_IP}:8000`

---

Reducing the bitrate may affect the latency only when the communication bandwidth is near full capacity (below some bitrate, the effect is negligible).